# How to chain awk print statements?

Tags: bash, awk, gnu, bsd, text-manipulation

Okay, here's a quick example; me isolating a host's IPV4 in three steps:

```
ip -br a  
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
eth0             DOWN           
wlan0            UP             192.168.0.101/24 fe80::9fcd:45fb:1e0f:a1cc/64
```

```
ip -br a | awk '/wlan0/ {print $3}'  
192.168.0.101/24
```

```
ip -br a | awk '/wlan0/ {print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'
192.168.0.101
```

Instead of invoking a second instance of `awk` (piping the output of one into the next); how can it be done all in one go?

---

Just wanted to say: The question isn't about parsing the output of `ip`. I just needed a quick example to help illustrate the question; this was the first thing that I came up with. The real question is summed up in the title.

Anyway, for what it's worth (I'll have to check it, but I'm pretty sure); this is what I've done in the (recent) past:

```
ip -br a s dev wlan0 | awk -F '[ /]*' '{print $3}'
192.168.0.101
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gsub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for that like:

```
ip -br a | awk '/wlan0/ {gsub(/\/.*/, ""); print $3}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the definition of field separator to include both spaces and `/`:

```
$ ip -br a | awk -F'[[:blank:]/]+' '/wlan0/{print $3}'
192.168.0.101
```

The option `-F'[[:blank:]/]+'` tells awk to use any combination of blanks, tabs or slashes as the field separator on input.

Comment: This gives the correct result for the `ip` example.  But the OP says that `ip` is *just* an illustrative example; the real question is: How do you do `awk '{print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'` in a single `awk` command, and this answer fails if the first or second (whitespace-delimited) word in the input line contains a `/`.  Specifically, it will output the third subfield of the first word, or the first or second subfield of the second word, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

For this instance, the easiest way to do it is probably set multiple separators using a regex:

```
ip -br a | awk -F '[\t /]*' '/wlan0/ {print$3}'
```

This makes the field separator any string of `/`, spaces, or tabs, and then prints the third field.

To do any *arbitrary* two commands you would like, you pretty much need to learn the full awk programming language. I would recommend against that- I'm sure you have better things to do with your time.

Comment: This gives the correct result for the `ip` example.  But the OP says that `ip` is *just* an illustrative example; the real question is: How do you do `awk '{print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'` in a single `awk` command, and this answer fails if the first or second (whitespace-delimited) word in the input line contains a `/`.  Specifically, it will output the third subfield of the first word, or the first or second subfield of the second word, in that case.

Comment: @G-Man I totally agree that my illustrative example is not a complete solution, but just a trick that works in this case. But that's my point- there's *not* a general method for chaining `awk` statements: you need a separate "trick" for every one. Thus "to do any *arbitrary* two commands, you pretty much need to learn the full awk programming language."

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers solve the underlying problem, they don't really answer the question, "How do I chain awk print statements?"

For this sort of problem, the answer is, "You don't." You use the rest of the language to manipulate the source until you get the desired result - which is what the other two answers do. You only use `print` to output the final result.

Once you have specified an initial range pattern such as `/wlan0/` (or `/^wl/` in my case because my WiFi has a different name), your action, the code inside `{}`, will only operate on input lines that contain that string.

Once you have that, you can do whatever you need to with that input line.

```
ip -br a | \
awk '
/^wl/ {
  ip1 = $3
  gsub(/\/.*/, "", ip1)
  print ip1
}
'
```

This code takes the desired field, puts it in a variable, edits the content of that variable, and then prints it.

The other answer does this same thing more efficiently, but this illustrates a more general case where other steps can be added. You could even save the result to use later with something found on another input line, etc.

For something that might actually look more like "print chaining", awk has an `sprintf()` function which can do a formatted print of its input into a variable for further processing.

Or, if you're printing more than one thing on a line, your code can use multiple `printf()` statements without a newline until the last one to build an output line piece by piece.

Comment: This is the best answer so far to the question:  How do you do `awk '{print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'` in a single `awk` command?  But how would you generalize this to `awk '{print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $4}'`?  For example, to print `fox` given the input `wlan0 foo/bar the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the lazy/dog`?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat in the spirit
of [Stephen Rauch’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1285325/354511#1285329) and [Joe’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1285325/354511#1285941), but better:

```
awk '/wlan0/ {split($3, a, "/"); print a[1]}'
```

This takes the third field (`$3`) and `split`s it,
using `/` as the separator. 
The components go into array `a`, and the number of subfields is returned. 
(In this snippet, I’m ignoring the return value.) 
So `a[1]` is the first `/`-delimited subfield of the third field.

This is more easily generalized than the other answers. 
For example, if your input is

```
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
wlan0 foo/bar the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the lazy/dog
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping—rapping at my chamber door.
```

then the command

```
awk '/wlan0/ {if (split($3, a, "/") < 4) print "There is no fourth subfield";
                                    else print "The fourth subfield is", a[4]}'
```

will print the fourth subfield of the third field of the third line (`fox`),
after checking the return value from `split`
to verify that there are (at least) four subfields. 
I.e., this is like

```
awk '/wlan0/ {print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $4}'
```

in a single `awk` command, with error-checking.